# How can i generate domain model diagrams, and documentation

Tags: import, documentation, enterprise-architect, domain-model, generated

I imported my project files into Enterprise Architect, under the Domain Model section. The program imported the files correctly, but it did not create domain model diagrams, so i can generate documentation about it, but it is empty.

If i imported the project files under the Class model section, class diagrams creates, and i able to generate documentation correctly. But i need the Domain Model.

So, how can i generate domain model diagrams, and a correct documentation with them?

Comment: maybe  the Domain model package related to a docuemntatino template that ignores diagrams, and the Class model package is related to another template that does generate diagrams. Try to change templates.

Comment: I checked the templates, and they are fine.

Comment: I do not have more ideas. Try to ask in EA experts forum: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi

Comment: What do you mean by "imported my project". Is it code RE?

Comment: Yes, it is. I imported the java programcode, and i want to generate a domain model, and generate a documentation from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in having EA generate diagrams for you (although that is possible as well). The only thing that will do is create huge, unreadable "wallpaper" diagrams.

You better create the diagrams yourself.

Just add a diagram in a package and start dropping classes onto it.

Once you have usable diagrams you can generate your documentation.